# How do you create a custom field that can only be changed via workflow rules?

Tags: youtrack

I am attempting to create a custom field in youtrack who's value changes along with state changes in another field.  I was wondering if there was a simple way to make this field read-only in the UI so that it cannot get out of sync with what it should be.

My current solution is to assert the correct states in a changed event (my actual rule is more complex):

```
rule Department should only be changed automatically

when Department.changed {
  var message = "Department change not allowed";
  assert Department != {Product Management} || State != {Submitted}: message;
  assert Department != {Development} || (State != {Open} && State != {In Progress}): message;
}
```

The issue is that if I want to tweak the state machine driving everything, I need to remember to come back to this rule as well to make sure everything remains consistent.  Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Your point is clear, but there's no way to make a field read-only in UI while keeping it updatable by a state machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the field to be updatedable by Global Admins and still be able to use workflow to update it. This works in YouTrack Cloud as of the date below.